# Jquery wait for Ajax call to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

If have this jQuery script to move files from ftp server 1 to ftp server 2. It does work, but I want move the files one by one and not all at once. Without freezing the browser with "async=false"..

```
 <script>
    var files = new Array();
    files[1]="testfile1.txt";
    files[2]="testfile2.txt";
    files[3]="testfile3.txt";


    $('#button').click(function() {
      $.each( files, function( key, value ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/move.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
        file: value
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#'+ key).html(data);
        }
      })
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that will get the next item in the `files` array, perform the AJAX call, and then calls itself in the `success` callback of that AJAX call.

```
var files = new Array(), key = 1;
// arrays are generally indexed starting at 0, but I left the below as is
files[1]="testfile1.txt";
files[2]="testfile2.txt";
files[3]="testfile3.txt";


function moveFile() {
    if(key < files.length) { // there's a next element
        var value = files[key];
        $.ajax({
            url: '/move.php',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                file: value
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#' + key++).html(data);
                moveFile();
            }
        });
    }
}

$('#button').click(moveFile);
```

I considered using `files.pop();` to get the next element, but since I wasn't sure whether you wanted the array to remain intact after this had run I decided to track the index to access them with instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it recursively:

```
var files = new Array();
    files[1]="testfile1.txt";
    files[2]="testfile2.txt";
    files[3]="testfile3.txt";

$('#button').click(function() { moveFile(files); });


function moveFile(fileArray) {
  var currentFile = fileArray.shift();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/move.php',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      file: currentFile
    }
  }).done(function () {
    if(fileArray.length > 0)
      moveFile(fileArray);
  });
}
```